# How to add reports in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the add new item there is an option to add report and add report wizard.
But I don't know how to work with that. Is there any blog or video available to learn that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I am absolutely sure of it. Have you checked YouTube?